# Values variables inside "this" class differ when created and during OnPress

Tags: c#, class, unity-game-engine

I am using a custom class to visualize DesignCards that are shown inside a dropdown menu after a button is pressed. The values are correct when these Cards are displayer, which I am sure of since they show the right image. However, after I call the "OnSelected" function trough the default "OnPress" event from Unity's Button component, it shows me in the log that it will always use the default values of this class (CardType being "Powersupply" and PartType being "A").

```
DesignCard Class:
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DesignCard : MonoBehaviour {

    public enum CardType { Powersupply, Sensor, Weapon, Module}
    CardType cardType = CardType.Powersupply;

    public enum PartType { A, B, C, D, E}
    PartType partType = PartType.A;

    private int inStock;
    private Transform MasterObject, contentList;
    private Sprite sprite;

    void Start ()
    {
        MasterObject = GameObject.Find("Master").transform;
    }

    public DesignCard (CardType mCardType, PartType mPartType, int mInStock)
    {
        cardType = mCardType;
        partType = mPartType;
        inStock = mInStock;
    }

    public void CreateCard(Transform mContentList)
    {
        Debug.Log("Created card with type: " + this.GetType().ToString() + " and model: " + this.GetModel().ToString());
        contentList = mContentList;
        GameObject go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load("TowerDesignScene/Card"), contentList);
        go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        sprite = GetImage(this);
        go.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite;
    }

    public CardType GetType()
    {
        return (cardType);
    }

    public PartType GetModel()
    {
        return (partType);
    }

    public Sprite GetSprite()
    {
        return (sprite);
    }

    public void AddToStock()
    {
        inStock++;
    }

    public int GetStock()
    {
        return (inStock);
    }

    public void OnSelected ()
    {
        Debug.Log("Pressed on card with type: " + this.GetType().ToString() + " and model: " + this.GetModel().ToString());
        MasterObject.GetComponent<TowerDesignMasterScript>().SetCard(this);
    }

    private Sprite GetImage(DesignCard mCard)
    {
        DesignCard.CardType cardType = mCard.GetType();
        DesignCard.PartType partType = mCard.GetModel();
        sprite = null;
        string imagePath = "TowerDesignScene/DesignCards/";
        if (cardType == DesignCard.CardType.Module) imagePath += "Module/";
        else if (cardType == DesignCard.CardType.Powersupply) imagePath += "Powersupply/";
        else if (cardType == DesignCard.CardType.Sensor) imagePath += "Sensor/";
        else if (cardType == DesignCard.CardType.Weapon) imagePath += "Weapon/";
        if (partType == DesignCard.PartType.A) imagePath += "Type A";
        else if (partType == DesignCard.PartType.B) imagePath += "Type B";
        else if (partType == DesignCard.PartType.C) imagePath += "Type C";
        else if (partType == DesignCard.PartType.D) imagePath += "Type D";
        else if (partType == DesignCard.PartType.E) imagePath += "Type E";

        sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>(imagePath);
        return sprite;
    }

}
```

Log when created a dropdown menu filled with Powersupplies and pressing each of the 5 buttons in the same order they are created:
(cleaned up the unneccesary lines)

```
Created card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Powersupply and model: B 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Powersupply and model: C 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Powersupply and model: D 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Powersupply and model: E 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)
```

Log when created a dropdown menu filled with Modules and pressing each of the 5 buttons in the same order they are created:
(cleaned up the unneccesary lines)

```
Created card with type: Module and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Module and model: B 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Module and model: C 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Module and model: D 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Created card with type: Module and model: E 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 35)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A 
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)

Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A
(Filename: Assets/Tower Design/Scripts/DesignCard.cs Line: 70)
```

I'm pretty sure this isn't some sort of bug, but I'm running out of ideas of where the source of my issue may be.

Thanks.

Comment: Could it be that you assign the first object for the OnPress event and then duplicated it for other objects? Then all objects are pointing to the same one.

Comment: The funny thing is that it would still say _Pressed on card with type: Powersupply and model: A_ if I created a dropdown of let's say Modules. In that case the first five lines would be: _Created card with type: Module and model: A_ followed by _Created card with type: Module and model: B_ followed by etc.. etc..

Comment: I am skeptical on the bug from Unity side. The main issue here s that you have inspector setup (drag and drop) and those are impossible to watch by code here. I would get to the button section and click the slot on the OnPress event to seee which object gets highlighted.